# How to configure google map on android

Tags: android, google-maps

I m working on android google map service. I have installed google play services with android sdk manager but still, I don't have that latlng class. Do anybody have any idea how to correct that...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running android project on physical device because google map is not supported on emulator.

Comment: My question is not that it is not running. But to create my project I need some necessary classes just like latlng class but I can't figure it out how to include that, do you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows->Android SDK Manager

Install google play service library in extras.

It will be stored in /android-sdk/extras/libproject/googleplayservices

Add that in your eclipse

Then in your project

Go to properties->Android->Add that library

It will work.

GoogleMap gm;

Marker myMarkerOne;

gm = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
             gm.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

LatLng one = new LatLng(12.786608, 80.221916);//LatLng points add more points

```
myMarkerOne = gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(one)
        .title("Lotus Pond Chennai")
        .snippet("Flats")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
```

Give like this it will work.

Comment: It is going to work after my project recognizes this LatLng class.
I don't have that, I want to know how to include that one.
Thanks for your quick reply